I need help remembering/knowing my Chinese name
So, when I (American) was in elementary school I went to a bilingual school to study Chinese and English. My Chinese teacher gave me a name, from my memory, that was 小酒 , putting it into Google translate confused me as it translates as small wine.
Is this a normal, actual name? Is this shorter for a longer name I forgot? Any help is really appreciated

If possible give me names that probably match more than 小酒 that I might've confused. I'm 100% sure my name began with 小, Xiao, 80% sure my name followed with 酒, Jiu

If it was Jiu, then was it definitely 酒? That seems unusual for a name, could it have been something else like 玖 or 纠？

I misspoke, I mean the character was 酒, or a character similar to it possibly.

It might help if you remember on what occasion he offered you the name.

Are you #9 in anything or any situation, like 9 brothers, 9th in a class or position in sitting arrangements, and so on? Calling someone 小酒 has the implication of being fond of liquor as the 小 in a certain context means a "follower",  a "kin", a "disciple" or "younger brother" of some sort. So, 小酒 is definitely not suitable as a name for a normal person.

I might've been 9 years old, haha. But, I guess that probably wasn't the character. Do you know any common name with 小- that I might've confused? My teacher was from mainland China if that helps

Micah is transliterated as 彌迦, could it be 小彌?

No I don't think so, but thank you

酒 means wine or any other alcoholic drink, if the character is indeed "酒", the name "小酒" probably means you can drink a lot or you did something with alcoholic drink.
if the character is just similar to the structure of "酒", you may find the answer with search the radical "酉". If it is similar to the pronunciation, try to find the character which sounds like Jiǔ.

Yes, the character was similar to the structure of 酉. Do you know any names that are similar to 小酒, or common names beginning with 小 I may have confused? My teacher was from mainland China or Singapore, if that helps

China mainland and Singapore both use simple Chinese. If the character was similar to the structure of 酉, could u remember where the 酉 is in the structure of the character? Because there are some others similar to 酉, such as 酋, 西, and some characters are combined by these structure, like 尊, 栖. So if u can remember the position of 酉, than it may bring a lot of help, the character pronunciation is also helpful.

Thank you, I believe it was either 尊 or 栖. Would 小尊 or 小栖 be normal names?

Both 小尊 or 小栖 is not common in daily life, names which are combined by 小 and another character always be nicknames. But nicknames' character should be common in daily life. So the key to find out the name teachers gave you is the pronunciation and the structure of the character.
For example, if you remembered that the character contains 西 and 西 is to the right of the character, you can used some Chinese character search tool to find which characters are combined by 西 to the right, and then you will get 䧈, 哂, 徆, 恓, 洒, etc.

Then sort out the character you need based on their pronunciation, if you remembered the character pronunciation is qī, 栖 may be the answer.

Could it be that the name the teacher gave you is "小九"?
9 is a very auspicious number in Chinese. Some of my Chinese friends will call their children's nickname "小九". Of course, as a nickname, "小酒" is also acceptable.Chinese people think that drinking a little wine is a very relaxed and elegant behavior.
According to legend, the dragon also had nine sons.
In short, your teacher's choice of this name expresses a kind of kindness.
I hope it is helpful to you.

No, if it was 小九 I'd definitely remember it, but it was most likely 小尊, 小栖, or 小西
